# Me dan el opio con tal gracia: ¿metafórico o literal?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

En la zarzuela *La verbena de la Paloma*, Don Hilarión canta sobre su infatuación con Casta y con Susana, diciendo que:

> Me dan el opio con tal gracia que no las puedo resistir.

En CVC [afirman](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=18025) que se trata de una expresión metafórica y que el acto de "dar el opio" significa coquetear.

No obstante, se puede observar que pocas líneas después, Don Hilarión dice:

> Caigo en sus brazos, ya dormido, y cuando llego a despertar.

Todo esto suena mucho al efecto del opio, es decir de la planta real.

¿Habla Don Hilarión de la literal administración del extracto de amapolas? ¿O simplemente está empleando una metáfora extendida?

Comment: No tengo claro de que se trate de una pregunta sobre la lengua.

Comment: Quiero saber el significado que una frase en español tiene en una oracion determinada, ya sea metaforico o literal. Dicho de otra forma, quisiera saber el significado de una expresion.

Answer (score 2):

Este tipo de expresiones se pueden encontrar en el diccionario de la RAE, en este caso buscando en la entrada para *[opio](https://dle.rae.es/opio)*:

> **dar el opio**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **embelesar**.

Y a su vez:

> **[embelesar](https://dle.rae.es/embelesar)**
>
> De *en-* y *belesa*.
>
> 1. tr. Arrebatar o cautivar los sentidos. U. t. c. prnl.

Esta expresión llega registrada en el DLE desde 1970, pero se lleva usando al menos desde finales del siglo XIX, como podemos ver en este ejemplo:

> *En tanto no daba el reló de Carabanchel ó el de Leganés las tres, hora designada para comenzar la fiesta, se entretuvo el TÍO JINDAMA en echar una ojeada por la plaza, en muchos de cuyos asientos habia muchas y lindísimas barbianas, capaces de dar el ópio á media humanidad, porque han de saber Vds. que las barbianas que asisten al espectáculo nacional siquiera sean novilladas, son hasta allí.*
>
> El Tío Jindama. 9/1/1881, [página 2](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0012244304&page=2&search=%22dar%20el%20opio%22&lang=es).

Teniendo en cuenta que *La verbena de la Paloma* es de 1894, posterior a este artículo, es muy probable que el uso de la expresión sea metafórico.

Comment: Ya había visto esto. Pero en ese caso, ¿por qué Hilarion quedaría dormido? ¿Es una extensión de la metáfora?

Comment: @Obie2.0 me temo que la interpretación del texto literario queda fuera del ámbito de este sitio, lo siento. Solo podríamos especular con la intención que el autor le quiso dar, lo que haría la pregunta subjetiva. Yo personalmente dudo mucho que se refiera al uso de opio real, pero interpretar si Hilarión se durmió de verdad o si simplemente se puso a soñar despierto, no podemos responderlo a ciencia cierta.